# How to create popover survey like Hotjar using javascript on client website?

Tags: javascript, django, hotjar

I have been using Django to create post purchase form, much like Google Form, using iframe to embed the form to the clients website.

But then I saw Hotjar and how they implement their form as a popover survey. In Hotjar, after the form is created, Hotjar gives a javascript trigger that can be pasted into the clients website.

I can create those stuff on my own website, but I am a bit lost on how those can be implemented on another website using javascript trigger. Does anyone have any tips on how to go on about implementing it myself?

P.S. I am not interested in tracking features of Hotjar, just survey.

So far I thought of creating Django templates and views to create questions and answers, and based on the inputs, then convert it into javascript and save it to Google Cloud Storage.

I thought maybe I can load it on clients website using Javascript. But not sure how or whether it is even a good idea.

Basically, I just want the client to paste some javascript code. And in doing so the forms (Questions, answers, and buttons) I created would appear at the bottom right corner of their own website as a popover.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.